# removing node in linkedlist using java

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to code a method for deleting the last Node in a linkedlist(for learning how to modify a linkedlist..I am not using the java library LinkedList class)..I tried to deal with the usecase where the passed linkedlist has only one Node.

However when I try to print the linkedlist before and after the removal, it gives the same output as if the node was not removed.

```
class NodeProcessing{
    public static void removeLastNode(Node f){
        if (f==null) return;
        if(f.next == null){//if linkedlist has single node
            f = null;
            return;
        }
        ...
    }

    public static void showList(Node first){
        System.out.println("linked list=");
        for(Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next){
            System.out.print(x.item+" ,");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node a = new Node();
        a.item = "one";
        showList(a);
        removeLastNode(a);
        showList(a);
    }

}
class Node{
    String item;
    Node next;
}
```

Output:

linked list=
one ,

linked list=
one ,

update:
when I used the debugger,I can see that the `Node a` in `main()` has address :`Node@a61164` 
and the `Node f` inside `removeLastNode()` also has :`Node@a61164`

Comment: You will find that it is a common question after you thinking, By Reference or By Value. When you set the Node null in Method "removeLastNode",it is just set the copy reference "f" to null, the real Node "a" is always point to the real value.By the way, you may change the Node.item in your Method.You may find some Heap and Stack details to look for the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `f` to null does nothing - that just changes the value of the *parameter*, which is just a local variable. It's important to understand that Java always uses pass-by-value for parameters - the value is a reference when the parameter type is a class type, but that reference is passed by value. Changing the parameter value to a different reference doesn't change the caller's argument.

Ideally you'd want to separate the concept of "the list" from "a node in the list" (just as the Java API does). That way when you call `remove` on a *list*, it mutates the *list itself*. In your current model of "a node is just the head of a list" there's no way you can remove the final node - you can't destroy the node itself.

The closest you could come would be to make `removeLastNode` *return* a `Node` reference - which could return `null` if the notional list is now empty.

Comment: In addition to Jon's answer it would be advisable to set the removed element to null after you have removed the node. It would help avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

The Node f is local variable in the following method

```
public static void removeLastNode(Node f)
```

Since it is a copy of the reference to the actual argument, the changes made to the parameters will not affect the arguments.

you are doing

```
f = null
```

where as

```
Node first
```

will be still pointing to the existing node.
You are using the argument to print the linked list, Hence the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java provided LinkedList data structure to do this.

```
    LinkedList items = new LinkedList();
    items.add("one");
    items.add("two");

    System.out.println(items);
    items.removeLast();
    System.out.println(items);
```

This will generate the desired output.

Comment: I am trying to learn how to write/edit a linkedlist from scratch..so I am conciously avoiding java's LinkedList

Comment: Should I remove this answer?

Comment: actually I had tried like this when I did not know linked lists in java.. So thought that you may have faced simillar